# Missing required parameters for route issue in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, error-handling, routes

In my laravel based application I have following link in my `admin.blade.php`

```html
<ul class="nav nav-treeview">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="{{ route('cms.home.create') }}" class="nav-link">
      <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
      <p>{{ __('Home Page') }}</p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In my project I have another blade called, `create.blade.php` which is in the following path

```
views/cms/home/create.blade.php
```

I have a controller called, `CmsHomeController.php` for that blade

In CmsHomeController I have a method called create

```php
public function create()
{            
    return view('cms.home.create'); 
}
```

Once the user clicks on the above mentioned link in the `admin.blade.php`, user should go to the `create.blade.php` blade.

And in my `web.php` I have registered my route as follows,

```php
Route::resource('cms.home','CmsHomeController');
```

But now the issue is,

When I click on that link in admin blade, I'm getting an error saying

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Missing required parameters for [Route: cms.home.create] [URI: cms/{cm}/home/create]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\mylaravelproject\resources\views\layouts\admin.blade.php)
```

In `create.blade.php` , I'm  having just a simple form

Where am I doing wrong and what would be the correct fix?

UPDATE:

I tried running

```
php artisan route:list
```

This is what I got

[image]

I don't have such a param called, 'cm'..

Comment: You can check your route name with this command php artisan route:list and check name against the route.

Comment: have a look at my answer i have just posted below!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using `dot (.)` operator in your resource route it will generating nested routes.

You need to change your route name with single name like **cms-home**  or **cms_home**

Then you can simple use it as:

```
Route::resource('cms_home','CmsHomeController');
```

In your blade you can call it:

```
<a href="{{ route('cms-home.create') }}" class="nav-link">
```

Please have look at this [referance](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#restful-nested-resources)

Comment: yes that seem to be the issue, changed my route to this, 
Route::get('/cms/home/create', 'CmsHomeController@index')->name('cms-home.create');
and it's working now. thanks for the guidance

Comment: @VolkaDimitrev Great!! Glad to help you on your concern.

Answer (score 0):

Your route need a parameter (cm)
You should have in your template `href="{{ route('cms.home.create', ['cm' => $id_cm]) }}"`

Comment: But i'm not passing any params to my method and what is this 'cm'?

Comment: I don't know your entire application, i just read the error message Missing required parameters for [Route: cms.home.create] [URI: cms/{cm}/home/create]

Comment: Well, I don't really have a param or a variable called 'cm'

Answer (score 0):

If you need the route be `cms.home`, try this:

```php
Route::resource('cms.home', 'CmsHomeController', [   
    'parameters' => ['cms' => 'cms']
]);
```